# reusable datatemplate binding to celltemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following datagrid

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:Foo}" x:Key="dTemp">
                <TextBox Background="{Binding BgColor}" Text="{Binding Path=RowId}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:Foo}" x:Key="dTemp2">
                <TextBox Background="{Binding BgColor}" Text="{Binding Path=Alias}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource dTemp}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource dTemp2}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

and in the codebehind I have:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows; 
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Foo[]> ObservableCollection;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Foo[]>();

        Foo[] ocoll = new Foo[3];
        ocoll[0] = (new Foo(1, "FIRST ARRAY FIRST ROW FIRST COLUMN", Brushes.Aqua));
        ocoll[1] = (new Foo(2, "FIRST ARRAY FIRST ROW SECOND COLUMN", Brushes.Red));
        ocoll[2] = (new Foo(3, "FIRST ARRAY FIRST ROW THIRD COLUMN", Brushes.Green));

        Foo[] ocoll2 = new Foo[3];
        ocoll2[0] = (new Foo(4, "SECOND ARRAY SECOND ROW FIRST COLUMN", Brushes.Aqua));
        ocoll2[1] = (new Foo(5, "SECOND ARRAY SECOND ROW SECOND COLUMN", Brushes.Red));
        ocoll2[2] = (new Foo(6, "SECOND ARRAY SECOND ROW THIRD COLUMN", Brushes.Green));

        this.ObservableCollection.Add(ocoll);
        this.ObservableCollection.Add(ocoll2);

        dataGrid1.DataContext = ObservableCollection;
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int RowId { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public Brush BgColor { get; set; }

    public Foo(int rowId, string @alias, Brush bgColor)
    {
        this.RowId = rowId;
        this.Alias = alias;
        this.BgColor = bgColor;
    }
}
}
```

The Object Foo has more than 30 properties (I only wrote 2 in here to make it easier to follow)..
the question is:
do I really have to define 30 different datatemplates (like dTemp, dTemp2, ... see above) to bind the CellTemplate of each DataGridTemplateColumn to it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create just one implicit `DataTemplate` for your data type *if you do not declare an `x:Key` value for it*:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:YourDataType}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextDescription}" Background="{Binding Color}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

This will automatically be applied to all of your instances of your data type that are within the scope of this `DataTemplate`, eg. put it in your control `Resources` or `Application.Resources` section.

UPDATE >>>

Unfortunately, you still don't seem to have it right. If you re-read my original answer, you should see that I specified that you *do not declare an x:Key value* for the `DataTemplate`.

Furthermore, you previously said that all of the `DataTemplate`s would be the same, but now you have added two different ones, so this method will no longer work.

UPDATE 2 >>>

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) states that 'A `DataTemplate` describes the visual structure of a data object'. It might be clearer if it said that a `DataTemplate` can show the properties of one type of data object. However, only one `DataTemplate` is required to be defined per object type *if you do not declare an `x:Key` value for it*. So if you define one for a particular type, *all instances of that type will be automatically rendered according to that `DataTemplate`*.

You asked me 'how to set the `DataTemplate` to display more than one element in it'... if by that you mean 'how to apply the `DataTemplate` to more than one instance of the defined data type', the answer is simply to *not declare an `x:Key` value for it* and do *not* set the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` property. Using this method would render each item with the *same* UI controls, but with the *different* values from each instance.

However, if you mean 'how to display different instances of the defined data type differently' as is currently shown in your question, then the answer is shown in your question... you would have to explicitly declare each one with a `x:Key` value and set the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` property to the named `DataTemplate`.

Comment: thank you for your answer...but the textbox is binded everytime to another element in the array... how will this be don't if I only have 1 Datatemplate ??

Comment: Did you try it? When the WPF Framework sees an instance of type `YourDataType` (in this example), it will look for a `DataTemplate`. First it looks to see if one has been declared explicitly, eg. using an `x:Key`. If one has not been set explicitly, it will look for any that are declared implicitly like this. If it finds one, it will apply it to *every* instance of that type that it finds, whether they are in a collection, or just a single object.

Comment: could you please check the code above ? I changed it to reflect my code ..thanks in advance

Comment: It is unfortunate that you changed your question... it is generally preferable for users to add further information to the end of their question so that answers that relate to the original question still make sense. I'll add to my answer.

Comment: well, if you check my original question you will see that the question is still the same ..please check it again I had myData[0].Color, and myData[1].Color and so on ..exactly like I now have ocoll & ocoll2 .. if you are just worried about the names, well sorry yes I changed them ..thanks anyway... and by the way how would I set the datatemplate to display more than one element in it !!!!!!!

Comment: I did look and your question is *not* the same... before you had identical `DataTemplate`s defined and now they're different. This changes the whole meaning of your question. I have updated my answer for you again.